# Question about implicit function theorem and regular points

Tags: differential-geometry

In the definition of a regular point, it says that a point $p$ in $U$, where $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is regular for a function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ if the differential $df(p)$ is of full rank. To me this makes sense whenever $m$ and $n$ are greater than one. In the definition of a regular value, it says that $q$ is a regular value if all points $p$ in $f^{-1}(\{q\})$ are regular points.

The implicit function theorem states that if we let $f$ be a function from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $q$ is a regular value of $f$, then $M = f^{-1}(\{q\})$ is a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I am trying to make sense of this but I don't understand what it means for a vector to be of full rank. Because since $f$ is from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the differential of $f$ at $p \in f^{-1}(\{q\})$ will be a vector, right?

Comment: The differential of $f$ at $p$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The differential will be $df(p) = \left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(p), \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(p), \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}(p)\right]$, right? I.e. a map given by a $1 \times 3$-matrix. What does it mean for such a matrix (when there is only one row) to have full rank?

Comment: It means that it has rank 1, i.e. it is not identically zero.

Comment: Thank you @studiousus !